# python parallel send 1000+ url requests and get content info

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, callback

I have a function that:
get the title and content of a new article and append into a list.

I want to:
Call 1000+ urls and run that function

Goal:
with one run, I'll get the 1000+ title and content in a list without having to loop through each url and call in sequence.

The code I have so far:

setup

```
import requests
from newspaper import Article
import threading
```

1)This is the "do work" function

```
def get_url_info(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url) 
        if r.status_code < 400: # if loads
            article = Article(url)
            article.download()
            article.parse()
            if detect(article.title) == 'en': #English only
                if len(article.text)<50: #filter out permission request
                    title = (article.title.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')) 
                    text = (article.text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
                    test_url= url
    except Exception as e:    
        issue = url #storing issue urls
        print(e, url) 

return title, text, test_url
```

2)This is the actual append into a list function:

```
def get_text_list():
    text_list = [] #article content list
    test_urls = [] #urls taht works
    title_list = [] #article titles
    url_list = get_tier_3()[:8000]  #get first 8000 english texts for testing
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(url,)) for url in url_list]
    for thread in threads:
    #originally this was for url in url_list
        thread.start()
        """
        title, text, test_url = call do work here
        title_list.append(title)
        text_list.append(text)
        test_urls.append(test_url)
        """
        print (i) #counts number of urls from DB processed

return text_list, test_urls, title_list
```

Question:
I don't know how to proceed after setting up the threads and get information from each thread

Comment: If you are hoping to improve efficiency, maybe look at aiohttp.  Here's an intriguing write-up (unfortunately the English isn't too polished): https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the `multiprocessing` module may be more well suited to this task. Because of the way CPython is implemented, it can't really achieve thread-based concurrency for CPU bound tasks (like HTTP requests) using the `threading` module.

I would also advise against spawning an individual thread or process for each URL you wish to process. You are extremely unlikely to realize any performance gains this way since all of the threads or processes will be fighting for system resources.

In general, a better solution is to spawn a fewer number of threads/processes and delegate a group of URLs to each one for processing. A simple way to implement this using a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) would be as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

NUM_PROCS = 4  # example number of processes to be used in multiprocessing

def get_url_info(url):
    ...

def get_text_list():

    # Get your list of URLs
    url_list = get_tier_3()[:8000]

    # Output lists
    title_list, text_list, test_urls = [], [], []

    # Initialize a multiprocessing pool that will close after finishing execution.
    with Pool(NUM_PROCS) as pool:
        results = pool.map(get_url_info, url_list)

    for title, text, test_url in results:
        title_list.append(title)
        text_list.append(text)
        test_urls.append(test_url)

    return title_list, text_list, test_urls
```

I hope this helps!